# What is the derivative of $f(x, y) = x + y^2$ with respect to $x$ if $y^2 = x^4$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

What is the derivative of $f(x, y) = x + y^2$ with respect to $x$ if $y^2 = x^4$?

This is what I have tried:

$ \frac{df}{dx} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{d x}{d x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{d y}{d x} = 2y * (\pm) 2x $.

Could you please help me understand if my solution is correct?

Comment: This function is bivariate though, so wouldn't you need to use partial derivates? To me it seems like trying to apply implicit differentiation.

Comment: Check the formula for the total derivative again. This is a multi-variable function and there are partial derivatives involved.

Comment: $\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dx} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: @Curiouserandcuriouser I edited that part in the question.

Comment: @Dick What is it that troubling you then. Just find the differentials and substitute.

Comment: As a function of $x$, you just have $x\mapsto x+x^4$

Comment: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is $1$, not $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the **OP**'s wonder, the most efficient route is simply to replace $y^2$ with $x^4$ in the original function so that we are led to:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x + x^4) = 1 + 4x^3$$

If there is a more general wonder about how to solve such problems using implicit differentiation, then read below the fold!

---

After carrying out implicit differentiation, you have:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x + y^2) = 1 + 2y \frac{dy}{dx}$$

You know that $y^2 = x^4$, which means that differentiating both sides of this latter equation with respect to $x$ will yield:

$$2y \frac{dy}{dx} = 4x^3 \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{4x^3}{2y}$$

Returning to the topmost equation, we now substitute this $\frac{dy}{dx}$ value to get:

$$1 + 2y \cdot \frac{4x^3}{2y} = 1 + 4x^3$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this case, what is the difference of this solution and directly substituting $y^2$ in f and performing differentiation with respect to x?

Comment: @Dick In terms of the answer? None! From the "what you have tried" it seemed to me that you were looking at partial derivatives, so I answered accordingly (trying to sketch out implicit differentiation steps). In any event, you can sub in directly and differentiating will yield the same solution of $1 + 4x^3$. Luckily, both lead to the same outcome :)

Comment: Thanks. I am just wondering if substituting is reasonable in any such case.

Comment: @Dick Yes: All works out in this case. I've edited my answer correspondingly!

Comment: @Dick - Substituting is always allowed, but there are plenty of cases where one can't directly solve for $y$ in terms of $x$, and so you have to use the implicit method.